# Load data from firebase to tableview inside a collection cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view where you scroll vertically. Inside each collection view cell I have a tableview which consists of comments. I load data from Firebase to both the collection view and tableview.

What I'm trying to do is to load specific data and the correct number of rows In the tableview inside the collection cell based on the photoID from a photo in my collection cell. Basically I want the right comments and the right numberofrows to each tableview inside each collectionviewcell

The problem is that the comments doesn't appear in the right cells and also the numberofrows in the tableviews In the different collection view cells are not correct.

in my collectionviewcontroller I use this Func to get my data.

```
                 func fetchData(){
             let ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("photos").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let photo = Photo(dictionary: dictionary)
            photo.videoId = snapshot.key
            self.photos.append(photo)
            if let photoId = photo.videoId{
                self.photoTimeStampDictionary[photoId] = photo
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cView.reloadData()
            }
            self.attemptReloadCollectionView()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

then in cellforitem.

```
    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]
    cell.photo = photo
    return cell
     // I then use the photo variable inside my collectionviewcell.
```

This is my database structure:

```
   **Comments**
                  **randomID**

                              [commenttext: "blabla"]
                              [uid: the senders UID]
                              [photo ID: the photoID]

    **Photos**

                  **photo ID**
                              [and some more info here ofc]
```

My model class.

```
                 class Comment: NSObject {
                 var commentId: String?
                 var commentText: String?
                 var photoId: String?
                 var timeStamp: NSNumber?
                 var uid: String?

init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    self.commentId = dictionary["commentid"] as? String
    self.commentText = dictionary["commenttext"] as? String
    self.photoId = dictionary["photoid"] as? String
    self.timeStamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? NSNumber
    self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String

}
```

}

The collection view works fine and just as it should.

This is what I have tried. (This is inside the collectionviewcell)

```
 var comments = [Comment]()

 func fetchData(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("comments").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let comment = Comment(dictionary: dictionary)
             //   comment.commentId = snapshot.key
            self.comments.append(comment)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.commentsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

and then in cellforrow:

```
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
        if comment.photoId == self.photo?.videoId{
            cell.commentText.text = comment.commentText
        }
```

photo is my model class  for all info connected to setting up the collection view cell except for the tableview. With the above code one specific comment that belongs to one specific picture ends up showing at several photos sometimes.

I would be grateful for help with this problem. I can imagine it has to do something with how you reload the tableview and also detect the index path in the collection view.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Wurzel

Comment: Why are you calling reloadData() asynchronously?

Comment: Hmm good question, I thought I had to do that because I then use the comments-array in my cellforrow. How would I do it instead?

Comment: added an answer below

Comment: the chaotic code indentation alone justifies a down vote.

Comment: Sad to hear, how would I post all necessary code to understand the problem otherwise? thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the asynchronous func :

var comments = Comment

```
 func fetchData(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("comments").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let comment = Comment(dictionary: dictionary)
             //   comment.commentId = snapshot.key
            self.comments.append(comment)
            self.commentsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

If that's indeed the issue, I will elaborate further.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the code above but the same problem still appears. I will update my code bit more so you can see how I fetch data from the collectionview!